# How to configure Phabricator to encrypt outgoing emails?

Tags: php, email, public-key-encryption, phabricator

Has somebody made [phabricator](http://www.phabricator.com/docs/phabricator/article/Configuring_Outbound_Email.html) to encrypt and decrypt outgoing and incoming emails? Do I need to write a customized code / plugin?

As I can do for jenkins: [How to configure Jenkins to send encrypted emails with gpg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154558/how-to-configure-jenkins-to-send-encrypted-emails-with-gpg)

Answer (score 2):

This looks extremely easy to me. For the outbound email just create:

**Some Custom Class You Write: use a custom adapter you write, see "Adapter: Custom".**
as the documentation states. To make it easier just copy some of the existing adapters and modify it to allow for encryption of the message.

Then for the incoming mail, considering you are using sendmail just follow this: **MTA: Configuring Sendmail** and create your custom email parsing logic along side with the decryption in the php file that will be used to parse the incoming mails as defined in the docs.